# Facebook messenger payment error

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I created a bot and I am trying to test Buy button following the instructions at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/payments#test_payments and I did set `is_test_payment` to true. But I got the error “(#1158) No valid payment provider found. Please add a valid payment provider, it can be tokenized payment, stripe or paypal.” I understand the payment is currently only available to US, but I found no place to specify the location of my page is US. How should I fix this?

Comment: Which payment provider have you set up?

Comment: @amuramoto I haven't set up with any payment provider yet. If I only want to test it with tokenized payment, do I still have to set up a payment provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set up a payment provider, even if you are going to be testing payments. Tokenized payments is the easiest way to go, just generate a key and add it with the Messenger Profile API.

Comment: Thank you. I will give a try. Do I also need to apply for Payment Beta Program if I just want to do testing?

Comment: Nope! Keep in mind you can only test with buy button right now. Webview doesn't support test payments yet unless you are doing a completely custom checkout in the webview.